# How to "save a session" in digikam?

Tags: digikam

I'm fairly new to [**digikam**](https://www.digikam.org/download/).

<sub>*(Previously I was using [Shotwell](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Shotwell) to sift through thousands of photos from various sources to separate the wheat from the chaff, but now feel digikam might be better suited for the job - and to ultimately get to a stage of properly managing digital assets, "DAM".)*</sub>

In my amateur and somewhat still haphazard workflow I am missing a - you would have thought! - simple feature, which one has become familiar with with modern web browsers: **(auto-)session save-and-restore**! I'm now reviewing one month ( = "album") at a time, applying a few filters, and get tired after getting halfway through a month (averaging some 3000 photos per month). If I then close digikam and restart it later I need to a) re-apply the filtering and b) find the place somewhere in that album where I took off. Ideally, digikam would open **exactly** as I left it. Currently I can't see a setting which would allow for this to happen. Am I overlooking something? A quick Google search also didn't reveal anything in this direction, hence my attempt at this posing this question here… Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered simply leaving the browser window open between sessions?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to apply the same effect to a series of images, have you tried the "Batch Queue Manager"? This will let you select the effects you want to apply, and from the "Queue" menu you can "Save workflow".

If you're looking to apply different effects to some images, and other effects to others, you could save them as two (or more) separate queues.

If you're looking to apply different effects to each image, I'm not sure that DigiKam does that. Personally, I like the way I can avoid this in DigKam - adjusting each image as I go. If I wanted to do that, I would use Darktable, which saves a .xmp file with each - though Darktable can be heavier going than DigiKam for image management, so I tend to review images and do some editing in the DigiKam Editor (basically an in-DigiKam GUI for Showfoto), but for more specific types of editing I'll use Darktable (which can be opened from DigiKam with a right click and "Open with" on each image).

Other editors and viewers are also supported by the right click from DigiKam - for example Rawtherapee and GIMP (though GIMP is more of a pain with RAW files).

It might be that others here will know a different trick, but since I've found that DigiKam is good for image management and Darktable for more specific editing, I use a combination of the two in, if you'll excuse the hi-fi metaphor, a separate-turntable-amplifier-and-speakers kind of approach.

Comment: The question above used "apply filters" not in the sense of image editing but in the sense of keyword/tag/star/...-filtering through thousands of photos to drill down to a ("qualit") selection of photos. Nothing to do with batch editing.

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty - Apologies, I'm old school - applying a filter to me will always suggest changing the light. Does creating a user defined tag in the Tag Manager and applying it only to the selected photos do what you want (and if not, where does this approach go wrong)?

Comment: Well, the idea is fair: it's like setting a bookmark (in a book), kind of. But it would still not save me from re-enabling a number of filters... it falls short of a *"save-state-and-restore-upon-startup-of-digikam"*.

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty - If I close Digikam (running on Ubuntu) and re-open it, it will go to the same tab (tag, date, search, etc.) as when I closed it. If I'm using "search" it'll go to the same results - though I could also "save current search" on the search tab. This sounds like what you might be hoping to see, but since it sounds like it isn't what you're seeing it's possible I've misunderstood. Which tab are you using to "apply filters", and what kind of things are you applying?

Comment: Tab (?): Albums/Thumbnails; Filters: one must-not-have-tag "abc" and must have zero stars. When re-starting digikam, it seems to be showing the "correct" album together with the zero-stars filter (only).